# Simple javascript counter no frills, just count

Tags: javascript, persistence, counter

I have the number  3,453,500 it needs to increase by +1 every 4 seconds.

Need to keep the formatting the same (commas in the right place)

(also is there a way that this can count continuously without the refreshing to the lowest number on page refresh?)

Comment: Please provide a code sample of what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty simple...

1. Retrieve the number from local storage and display it

   ```
   var num = +localStorage.getItem('num') || 3453500;
   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = num.toLocaleString();
   ```
2. Setup an interval to update the number every 4 seconds, save it and display it

   ```
   setInterval(function() {
       num++;
       document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = num.toLocaleString();
       localStorage.setItem('num', num);
   }, 4000);
   ```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28mk8j98/)</kbd>